# Vis JS/ Cytoscape JS label collision

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, vis.js

I was experimenting with a couple of JS graph libraries, and I have come across a problem with labels. I have many edges coming from various nodes (creating a link analysis graph)  and I need to be able to display labels on the edges. Without having them only appear on mouseover, is there any option to avoid label collisions on edges in either of these libraries. 
See an example of what I mean here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUJIr.jpg

The first is an example of what would be acceptable, none of the labels overlap with each other. The second is what I am getting now.
I would be fine with using either library which has this functionality.
Thanks in advance!
-Yash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a strictly planar graph, you will have edge overlap no matter what library you use.  That's a property of graph theory in general.

If you have overlapping edges, you'll also likely have overlapping labels.

You can try to reduce the likelihood of label overlap with choice of layout and styling.  For example, [autorotated edge labels](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels) will often reduce overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added in the changes you mentioned. Just wondering, is there a way to offset the label on an edge if it is on the same position as another label? Another way of asking this question, is there a way I can find the coordinates of a given label?